# Each line of content wrapped in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I'm having trouble troubleshooting an issue on [provemath](http://provemath.org?nodeid=testnode) where the content is not rendering as desired.

The problem is that each line (except for the first) in written content is wrapped in a `<div>`.  For example, the content

```
line1.
line2.
```

as you can see through the Safari web inspector is actually rendered as `<p>line1.<div>line2.</div></p>`.  The DESIRED output is `<p>line1.<br>line2.</p>`.

There are a few things that could be coming into play here...

1. I'm not sure how the browser takes in typed newlines.
2. My content rendering function (included below) runs Markdown (actually, [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked)) and some regexs.
3. CSS (included below) manipulates how some things are displayed, and I'm wondering if it can cause changes in the HTML itself.  I previously thought the use of `flexbox` was causing this, but I changed the CSS to no avail.

Content rendering happens as follows:

Content is typed by user (hitting RETURN for a new line) and captured with jQuery's `.html` function

```
blind.value = $value.html()
```

to get the content, and then processed with

```
function render_content(string) {
    // make all \ into \\ instead, so that they will be \ again when marked is done. This is for MathJax postrender compatability.
    string = string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
    string = string.replace(/\n/g, '<br />') // not doing anything AFAIK
    string = marked(string)

    string = string.replace(/img(\d+)/g, '<img src="image/$1.jpg" />')
    string = string.replace(/\\includegraphics\{(.*?)\}/g, '<img src="image/$1.jpg" />')

    return string
}
```

The CSS is as follows:

```
    .value {
        // display: inline-flex;
        display: inline;
        // flex-direction: column;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 85%;
    }
```

you can see the old CSS commented out.

Comment: ... which browser do you use ?   look at line intuition  at test me <br>again .. it did generate a br

Comment: @G-Cyr That's strange.  Your input doesn't have the issue.  I have tried this on Opera (Chromium) v 46 and Safari v 9.1.3.  Did you hit "ENTER" on your keyboard when inputting content?  That's what I did.

Comment: yes that's what i did, with the latest FF for windows,  OUPS  !!! just testing with chrome ... and it goes off your way  p is closed and a div is generated:(

Comment: Things work as desired on Firefox v 54 for Mac also.

Comment: "CSS (included below) manipulates how some things are displayed, and I'm wondering if it can cause changes in the HTML itself. I previously thought the use of flexbox was causing this, but I changed the CSS to no avail." Just want to note that no, CSS is not capable of changing actual HTML elements.

Comment: I have a "simple" solution in mind already, but don't want to say anything yet.  There is possibly a "best" solution for the situation that I'm not thinking of.  Please feel free to post your ideas as answers.

Comment: It seems to be appending divs from the file config-optimized.min.js. Is any function from that file used to render the data. Because when I edit and save anything on site itself, extra div is not created.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you processing 'backslash' before 'newline'? Have you tried this?

```
string = string.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')
string = string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
string = marked(string)
```

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping both lines in a div, then using css grid to render them as you like. Here is [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3LRtAm2SOo) documenting the css grid.

Comment: This is not the desired output.  The question clearly states the desired output will have lines *not* wrapped in `<div>`.  This is wanted for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having an answer, the solution was to use a regex to delete occurrences of `<div>` and `</div>` that certain browsers add.

Since user input is escaped, this could not get confused with a user manually typing "", since THAT user input would result in an HTML-escaped string (and would not produce a div, merely text that says "").